# Is there approach to map dictionary keys/values simultaneously in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, mapping

Referring to: *Swift Standard Library > Dictionary > [map(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1689397-map)*

> Returns **an array** containing the results of mapping the given closure
>   over the sequence’s elements.

As mentioned, we can do mapping in dictionaries, but the output will be *an array*, not a "mapped" dictionary.

Honestly, I'm not pretty sure if saying "mapping the whole dictionary" is legal, but what I mean is the following:

Consider that we have:

```
let myDict = ["1": "one","2": "tow","3": "three"]
```

and we want to map the whole thing! (both keys and values). Output should be:

```
let mappedDict = ["03": "THREE", "02": "TOW", "01": "ONE"]
```

Let's assume that the goal of the mapping is to add "0" as a first character to all keys and let all values to be upper-cased.

To make it more readable, I posted a solution (what I tried) as an answer instead of mentioning it in the question it self; I think my answer is not so *elegant* (or at least how I feel about its code smell), I mapped the keys, the values and combine them in a dictionary, each step has been achieved independently.

So, What I am asking about is:

Is there a way to do this job directly in one step? Something similar to:

*This snippet is a demonstration of what I'm asking about, code won't work fine*

```
let myDict = ["1": "one","2": "tow","3": "three"]
let mappedDict = myDict.map { key, value in
    "0" + key
    value.uppercased()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let myDict = ["1": "one","2": "tow","3": "three"]
let mappedDict = myDict.reduce([:]) { (result, pair) -> [String: String] in
    var result = result
    result["0" + pair.key] = pair.value.uppercased()
    return result
}
```

Comment: Note that `reduce` will create an intermediate dictionary for each iteration, making it run in quadratic, rather than linear time. A simple `for` loop is cleaner, shorter and *will* run in linear time in this case.

Comment: @Hamish as a performance, could you please describe it in a simple way what's the difference?

Comment: @AhmadF The difference is that a `for` loop [such as suggested in my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342582/is-there-approach-to-map-dictionary-keys-values-simultaneously-in-swift#comment69887453_41342591) is able to mutate the resultant dictionary directly (due to C.O.W optimisation where there's only a single reference to the buffer). `reduce` on the other hand will *copy* the resultant dictionary at each iteration, meaning that the resultant dictionary will be iterated over for each iteration that `reduce` does – therefore running slower than the `for` loop.

Comment: @Hamish I agree with you at this point. `reduce` may be slower than simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
let myDict = ["1": "one","2": "tow","3": "three"]

let mappedKeys = myDict.map { "0" + $0.key } // ["02", "01", "03"]
let mappedValues = myDict.map { $0.value.uppercased() } // ["TOW", "ONE", "THREE"]

var mappedDict = [String: String]()

let zippedArray = Array((zip(mappedKeys, mappedValues)))

for element in zippedArray {
    mappedDict[element.0] = element.1
}

print(mappedDict) // ["03": "THREE", "02": "TOW", "01": "ONE"]
```

To be more clear, the above code snippet doing the following:

- Mapping the dictionary keys.
- Mapping the dictionary values.
- Create a new empty dictionary `mappedDict` to append to it.
- Combining mapped keys/values into `zippedArray` (using `zip`).
- Filling `mappedDict` via *for-loop*.

Comment: Why don't you just change the keys and add the values directly to `mappedDict` instead so you can skip creating `mappedKeys`, `mappedValues` and `zippedArray`.

Comment: There's no need to convert the zipped sequences into an `Array`, you can iterate over them directly. Also why not just iterate over the dictionary directly and apply the transformations to the keys and values in the loop? (e.g `for (key, value) in myDict { mappedDict["0" + key] = value.uppercased() }`)?

Comment: @Eendje I'm separating them just to make it more readable... btw, do you think that the whole answer is a good solution?

Comment: Well, no. I would do exactly like how Hamish has suggested. It's more clear and shorter.

Comment: It's not about doing some "silly" mapping, this is just an example. The idea is what if mapping case should be done, is the only way to do it is using a for loop and map key and values independently?